# How to hide Side Panel and the add data popup when the map is created?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, kepler.gl

Trying to create a Kepler.gl map and passing dynamic data and do some actions on the map, I followed this [tutorial](http://vis.academy/#/kepler.gl/setup) and added data layers and everything working with the data, but now I need to hide the Side Panel on creating the map how can I do that, do i need to add something to the KeplerGl state? so when it's initing don't show the Side Panel, or I need to use the map actions [toggleSidePanel](https://github.com/uber/kepler.gl/blob/master/src/actions/ui-state-actions.js)? and how can I use this action, also I need to hide or remove the add data popup, please help and many thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in step 3 of the vis academy tutorial you will find the following code:

`// addDataToMap action to inject dataset into kepler.gl instance
this.props.dispatch(addDataToMap({datasets: dataset, config: nycConfig}));`

addDataToMap can take a third parameter where you can pass few options to interact with Kepler.gl UI.
In your case what you want to do is the following:

`// addDataToMap action to inject dataset into kepler.gl instance
this.props.dispatch(addDataToMap({datasets: dataset, config: nycConfig, options: {centerMap: true, readOnly: true}}));`

Kepler.gl will automatically hide the left panel for you.

Let me know if that works for you

Answer (score 0):

It didn't work for me with `readOnly` flag.

You can hide panel and the popup at the time of initializing the kepler reducer.

```
const keplerReducer = keplerGlReducer.initialState({
    uiState: {
        activeSidePanel: null,  
        currentModal: null      
    }
});
const reducers = combineReducers({
    keplerGl: keplerReducer,
    app: appReducer
});
```